# how to extract data from text file in Java

Tags: java, file, file-io

```
while (myFile.hasNextLine()) {
```

`if(myFile.next().equals("Oval")) {
            System.out.println("this is an Oval");

        }

        else if(myFile.next().equals("Rectangle")) {
            System.out.println("this is an Rectangle");

        }`

the file contains the following
Oval    10 10 80 90 Red
Oval    20 20 50 60 Blue
Rectangle 10 10 100 100 Green

I want to extract the data and pass them to a specific constructor according to the type indicated at the beginning of the line.

but I am getting this weird output

> this is an Oval
>   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>   this is an Rectangle
>       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
>   this is an Rectangle
>       at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
>       at TestMain.main(TestMain.java:33)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Understand that when you call `next()` on a Scanner object, it eats the next token, and then returns it to you. If you don't assign the String returned to a variable, it's lost forever, and the next time you call `next()` you get a new token. Much better to get the token, assign it to a String variable and then do your if tests. Don't call `next()` in the if boolean test block.

i.e., something like:

```
while (myFile.hasNextLine()) {

    // get the token **once** and assign it to a local variable
    String text = myFile.nextLine();

    // now use the local variable to your heart's content    
    if(text.equals("Oval")) {
        System.out.println("this is an Oval");

    }

    else if(text.equals("Rectangle")) {
        System.out.println("this is an Rectangle");

    }
```

---

Also, if you test for `hasNextLine()` then you should call `nextLine()`, not `next()`, and you should call it only ***once*** for each hasNextLine.

---

When extracting lines of data from a text file, I sometimes use more than one Scanner. For instance:

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(myFile);
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
  Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(fileScanner.nextLine());

  // use the lineScanner to extract tokens from the line

  lineScanner.close();
}
fileScanner.close(); // likely done in a finally block after null check
```

Comment: Either call `next()` and after `nextLine()` to throw away the line, since the OP is only checking for "Oval" and "Rectangle" or split the String and take the first part.

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't know that, one more think how can I get rid of the `NoSuchElementException` ?, shouldn't be ok to use `hasNextLine()` to loop through out the file ?

Comment: @RootOfMinusOne: you can loop through the file any way you please as long as it works and respects the file's structure. I often use a File-based Scanner to get each line via `hasNextLine()` / `nextLine()`, and then use a separate String based Scanner to extract the individual tokens on the line. But if you go this route, be sure to dispose of each String-based Scanner when done with it.

Comment: @RootOfMinusOne: see edit for an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match your `next()` with a `hasNext()` method call to match an individual String token

```
while (myFile.hasNext()) {
   String token = myFile.next();

    if (token.equals("Oval")) {
       System.out.println("this is an Oval");
    }
    ...
}
```